# Linking To Location On Page - Slow Loading Affects Location

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I'm trying to link to a specific location on a page, but IE seems to load slower, which is throwing my location off.
So in my navigation I have a link like `http://mySite/myPage#myLocation`
The very first time I go to that link, in IE, it doesn't go to the proper location because images are still loading on the page.  It will hit it initially, but then get pushed down the page as other things load.  If I come back to the page, it's fine.  If I clear the cache and try again, I can replicate the problem.  Chrome and FF work fine.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's a quick solution I came up with that works.  Not sure if this is the best, but it's working.
If the location gets shifted around during the load, it will go back to that location after the page is fully loaded.

```
//Get the location ID if it exists in the URL, strip off #
var pageLocation = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];

//After page fully loaded, redirect to that location
//Prevents location from getting pushed away during IE slow page load
if (typeof pageLocation != "undefined") {
    window.onload = function () {
        location.hash = pageLocation;
    }
}
```